# Journal voucher menu not appearing in odoo 8

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, odoo-8

In openerp 7, I was using journal vouchers from accounting module  to track company expenses such as invoice,bank charges,employee expense etc but now in odoo 8 I can't see that menu in accounting module.I want that as my company clients are requesting for some customization on that.This is a screenshot from openerp 7. In odoo 8 journal voucher column is missing.[image]

[image]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Du6OX.png see this picture  it already there in odoo 8...

Comment: Hey I have added image from my pc, why I am not getting journal voucher column do I have to configure something?Plz reply back

Comment: are sure Online Billing or account_voucher module installed in your database?

Comment: yes online billing module is already installed but i am getting only journal items and journal entries not able to see journal vouchers

Comment: please rebase your branch form git and create a new database for and try this may be work for you...

Comment: Should i delete everything and reinstall?

Comment: if your data is important then you can update all module if not important the you can create a new database

Comment: I updated accounting,einvoicing,account_voucher modules still journal voucher is not appearing I even created new database there also its not appearing.I think in odoo 9 also its not there

Comment: in odoo 9 there is new name of voucher Entry  instead of  journal voucher and in odoo 8 is this problem in your customization so can you check it online instens of odoo and tell me